# Xcode source control issue (All projects are already under source control)

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

The last 5 or 10 sessions, whenever I go to start source control (Source Control > Create Working Copy), I'm prompted by a message "All projects are already under source control." For each of these projects that this message popped up on, I went to the directory of the session in Terminal and ran ls -a to check for hidden files and see if .git files really existed. I did this in the directory the Xcode sessions are located and went back one folder at a time, checking each folder for .git files as well, but none of the parent directories have .git files either. The only way I can get Xcode to start source control is if I use terminal to make the first git commit:
git init git add . git commit -m "Initial Commit."  This never used to happen before, I used to always be able to start source control through Xcode.
Then I can use Xcode source control after.
Anyone know of a fix?
On OS 10.12.3 and Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: This did not solve the issue for me.

Comment: If your current file is not under version control (no `.git` folder), for the first time, you should use git command to initial a git repo (as the way you used).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

1.Create an empty repo on github.

2.In source control navigator, select Remotes > Add Existing Remote

3.Put the repo link created in step 1 in Location and name it.

4.Push your repo.

Answer (score -1):

The message ***All projects are already under source control***, means the project has already controled by git (`.git` folder in the same path or as the parent path of the). So what you need to do for the project in xcode is to commit/pull/push. Or you can config the project by source control -> project (usually above **create working copy** item) -> configure git.

If you want add a file in the same git repo, you should add a file in the path same as `.git` or it's sub-path, then in xcode -> source control -> commit -> select the file you added -> commit.

If you want to do source control for another project, you should close the current project, and then reopen xcode with another project.

Comment: I do not see the  `create working copy` under the source control.
In the Create Git Repositories:
All projects are already under source control.